# jquery bubble popup Can not load jquerybubblepopup-themes

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, jquery-plugins

.I want to use jquery bubble popup to create a bubble.
I read that the folder “jquerybubblepopup-themes” should be copied in the root of my website.
Also, I have a jsp that isn't directly under the root of my website, but under "mywebsite/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/myfile.jsp". It contains this javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.infoTip').CreateBubblePopup({
themeName: 'black',
themePath: 'jquerybubblepopup-themes'                                                                
});
});
</script>
```

I read that in "themePath", the relative path of "jquerybubblepopup-themes" should be set.

In my case, "jquerybubblepopup-themes" can't be loaded, how could I modify themePath value so that the file "jquerybubblepopup-themes" will be loaded ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using  themePath: '/jquerybubblepopup-themes'

Comment: yes, I tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: I also tried '.../jquerybubblepopup-themes' but this didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

You should see errors in the browser console, ther you can see where it is trying to search for the themes (path), and adjust the path accordingly